# RequireJS and text plugin Load timeout for modules

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs

I am having some problems getting the RequireJS text plugin to work. This is possibly a path related issue (or something similarly obvious) but I can't solve it because neither the chrome console (with xhr turned on) nor firebug is giving me any info other than

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: text 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

I am quite sure that the paths are OK but I cant find any other explanation. Does somebody have an idea how to debug this?

I am using node.js and express on the server side and backbone and jQuery on the client end. All of these get loaded correctly with RequireJS.

Comment: have you placed the txt plugin in the correct folder as the docs suggest? Seems your txt plugin cant be loaded.

Comment: jupp, its in the same folder as main.js and I also tried providing a path with require.conf. Loading text as a module without providing anything for it to load seems to work ok also.

Comment: Do the chrome developer tools show you what request is being made for the text plugin on the network tab?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing it's a path issue. I have the same setup (node/express and backbone) and it seems to be working for me. Here is my main.js file:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery-1.7.1.min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone',
    text: 'libs/text',
    templates: '../views',
    persist: 'libs/persist/persist'
  }
});
require([
  'app'
], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

and here is how I call the plugin from within a module:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/sub_elements',
  'collections/elements',
  'views/element',
  'text!../../../views/partials/_elements.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, sub_elementsCollection, collection, view,     template){

  var elementsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ... //
  });

  return elementsView;
});
```

Comment: My paths are correct as well, and it works in a browser. However, I get the timeout error in the wp7Phone emulator.

Answer (score 1):

As it's on your windows phone, try to set "waitSeconds" to a higher number.

Mobile are slow, but require.js will timeout after 7 seconds by default, which is often way to low for mobile experience / or user with slow internet access.

doc: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds

Answer (score 1):

## My original answer

[I answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310978/312743) pointing to the official [require.js troubleshooting pages](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout).

**In my case this error only occurred when the developer console was open** on chrome for several chrome versions on a single macbook. Other devices didn't show the problem. Because of this I was OK by changing the config on that single computer.

## waitSeconds

The [waitSeconds option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds) can be configured as infinite (0) or any value you want (in seconds). The default value is 7 seconds. An example config:

```
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({
    baseUrl: "/another/path",
    paths: {
      "some": "some/v1.0"
    },
    waitSeconds: 0
  });
  require( ["some/module", "my/module", "a.js", "b.js"],
    function(someModule,    myModule) {
      //This function will be called when all the dependencies
      //listed above are loaded. Note that this function could
      //be called before the page is loaded.
      //This callback is optional.
    }
  );
</script>
```

**Since infinite (0) disables the timeout I would not recommend this option for production code!** If you encounter this problem running your code anywhere or disabling the timeout doesn't help then keep on reading.

### 3 common causes for this issue

- errors in modules you're loading
- wrong paths in configuration (check `paths` and `baseUrl` option)
- double entry in config

*For more on this topic check the original answer linked on top.*

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when incorrectly using the [syntax sugar](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded).
You can't both define dependencies and use the `require` factory function.

```
//THIS WILL FAIL
define(['require'], function (require) {
    var namedModule = require('name');
});
```

From [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded):

> This fails because requirejs needs to be sure to load and execute all
>   dependencies before calling the factory function above. If a
>   dependency array is given to define(), then requirejs assumes that all
>   dependencies are listed in that array, and it will not scan the
>   factory function for other dependencies. So, either do not pass in the
>   dependency array, or if using the dependency array, list all the
>   dependencies in it.

So if you specify a dependency array, you can't also depend on the sugar syntax to work. Not ideal in my opinion, but that's how requirejs was created to function.

Answer (score 0):

Require.js made a request for my `text.js` file, but the response was a `302` - my user was not authenticated. Therefore, `text` plugin couldn't load. Therefore all my text resources failed to load:  `text!any/name.html`.

My console gave me a related message, another hint that my `text` plugin couldn't load:

> Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined