# Require.js Error: Load timeout for modules: backbone,jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to use r.js to optimize my code but I keep running to this error:

Tracing dependencies for: init

```
Error: Load timeout for modules: backbone,jquerymobile
```

The command I am running is this:

```
$ java -classpath /Users/dixond/build-tools/rhino1_7R4/js.jar:/Users/dixond/build-tools/closurecompiler/compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main /Users/dixond/build-tools/r.js/dist/r.js -o /Users/dixond/Sites/omm_mobile/js/build.js
```

My build.js file looks like this:

```
( {
    //appDir: "some/path/",
    baseUrl : ".",
    mainConfigFile : 'init.js',
    paths : {
        jquery : 'libs/jquery-1.8.3.min',
        backbone : 'libs/backbone.0.9.9',
        underscore : 'libs/underscore-1.4.3',
        json2 : 'libs/json2',
        jquerymobile : 'libs/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min'
    },
    packages : [],
    shim : {
        jquery : {
            exports : 'jQuery'
        },
        jquerymobile : {
            deps : ['jquery'],
            exports : 'jQuery.mobile'
        },
        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        },
        backbone : {
            deps : ['jquerymobile', 'jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    keepBuildDir : true,
    locale : "en-us",
    optimize : "closure",
    skipDirOptimize : false,
    generateSourceMaps : false,
    normalizeDirDefines : "skip",
    uglify : {
        toplevel : true,
        ascii_only : true,
        beautify : true,
        max_line_length : 1000,
        defines : {
            DEBUG : ['name', 'false']
        },


        no_mangle : true
    },
    uglify2 : {},
    closure : {
        CompilerOptions : {},
        CompilationLevel : 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        loggingLevel : 'WARNING'
    },
    cssImportIgnore : null,
    inlineText : true,
    useStrict : false,
    pragmas : {
        fooExclude : true
    },
    pragmasOnSave : {
        //Just an example
        excludeCoffeeScript : true
    },
    has : {
        'function-bind' : true,
        'string-trim' : false
    },
    hasOnSave : {
        'function-bind' : true,
        'string-trim' : false
    },
    //namespace: 'foo',
    skipPragmas : false,
    skipModuleInsertion : false,
    optimizeAllPluginResources : false,
    findNestedDependencies : false,
    removeCombined : false,
    name : "init",
    out : "main-built.js",
    wrap : {
        start : "(function() {",
        end : "}());"
    },
    preserveLicenseComments : true,
    logLevel : 0,
    cjsTranslate : true,
    useSourceUrl : true
})
```

And my init.js looks like this:

```
 requirejs.config({
      //libraries
      paths: {
          jquery:       'libs/jquery-1.8.3.min',
          backbone:     'libs/backbone.0.9.9',
          underscore:   'libs/underscore-1.4.3',
          json2 :       'libs/json2',
          jquerymobile: 'libs/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min'
      },

      //shimming enables loading non-AMD modules
      //define dependencies and an export object
      shim: {
          jquerymobile: {
              deps: ['jquery'],
              exports: 'jQuery.mobile'
          },
          underscore: {
              exports: '_'
          },
          backbone: {
              deps: ['jquerymobile', 'jquery', 'underscore', 'json2'],
              exports: 'Backbone'
          }
      }
    });


requirejs(["backbone",], function(Backbone) {
    //Execute code here
});
```

What am I doing wrong in this build process?

Comment: I have the same problem , but only happens in chrome , in your case too ?

Answer (score 115):

Require.js has a Config option called waitSeconds.  This may help.

[RequireJS waitSeconds](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds)

Here's an example where waitSeconds is used:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    enforceDefine: true,
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths: {
        "jquery": "libs/jquery-1.8.3",
        "underscore": "libs/underscore",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone"
    },
    shim: {
        "underscore": {
            deps: [],
            exports: "_"
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
    }
});

define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
    function ($, _, Backbone) {
        console.log("Test output");
        console.log("$: " + typeof $);
        console.log("_: " + typeof _);
        console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same problem but I didn't think that it was actually a timeout issue. It must be due to the size or complexity of jQuery because the error only occurs when a dependency is declared on jQuery. Changing `waitSeconds` to something larger allowed the build to complete successfully.

Comment: I can confirm this. We have a bigger project with several dependencies to large libraries. With requireJS 2.0.6, that was fine. requireJS 2.1.4 however runs into the timeout. A higher value for `waitSeconds` solved it.

Comment: Just opened a pull request to update the build.js example of require.js so that people become faster aware of the parameter. See https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/pull/362

Comment: Thanks! This helped me. I wonder, are most folks using a non-default value for this property? Is 200 pretty common? What about 0?

Comment: I also get a timeout in iOS/Safari (and not iOS/Chrome!) when loading the first time after cache is cleared. Backbone views fail to load with timeout. Setting waitSeconds really high does not help. My require() call includes 8 modules, each of which include 2 - 3 of their own modules (some being text! templates). If I reduce the 8 modules to 5, things load fine under iOS/Safari. I've checked the file paths as well as for syntax errors a dozen times.

Comment: I got timeout error too although the module was loaded successfully (HTTP responded 200) and module code executed well. Set waitSeconds to 2000 dismissed this error.

Answer (score 43):

## The Error

I recently had a very similar issue with an `angularJS` project using `requireJS`.

I'm using Chrome canary build (`Version 34.0.1801.0 canary`) but also had a stable version installed (`Version 32.0.1700.77`) showing the exact same issue when loading the app with `Developer console` open:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules
```

**The developer console is key here** since I didn't get the error when the console wasn't open. I tried resetting all chrome settings, uninstalling any plugin, ... nothing helped so far.

## The Solution

The big pointer was a Google group discussion (see resources below) about the `waitSeconds` config option. Setting that to 0 solved my issue. I wouldn't check this in since this just sets the timeout to infinite. But as a fix during development this is just fine. [Example config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config):

```
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({
    baseUrl: "/another/path",
    paths: {
      "some": "some/v1.0"
    },
    waitSeconds: 0
  });
  require( ["some/module", "my/module", "a.js", "b.js"],
    function(someModule,    myModule) {
      //This function will be called when all the dependencies
      //listed above are loaded. Note that this function could
      //be called before the page is loaded.
      //This callback is optional.
    }
  );
</script>
```

**Most common other causes for this error are:**

- errors in modules
- wrong paths in configuration (check `paths` and `baseUrl` option)
- double entry in config

## More Resources

Troubleshooting page from requireJS: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout point 2, 3 and 4 can be of interest.

Similar SO question: [Ripple - Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: app http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736547/ripple-uncaught-error-load-timeout-for-modules-app-http-requirejs-org-docs)

A related Google groups discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/70HQXxNylYg

Comment: Setting timeout to infinite is great as it saves us from setting an exact timeout cap. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

In case others have this issue and still struggling with it (like I was), this problem can also arise from circular dependencies, e.g. A depends on B, and B depends on A.

The [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) don't mention that circular dependencies can cause the "Load timeout" error, but I've now observed it for two different circular dependencies.

Comment: How did you go about identifying circular issues? Did you have to go through each defined module?

Comment: My issue came up when I added and changed some modules, so I was able to go through those changes, track down which added dependencies created the circular dependency loop, and remove them.

Comment: [xrayquire](https://github.com/requirejs/xrayquire) (a tool by requirejs) can check for circular dependencies

Comment: observed when loading a module A inside a callback function from another module B which required module A

Answer (score 17):

Default value for waitSeconds = 7   (7 seconds)

If set to 0, timeout is completely disabled.

src: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the issue is that *Require.js* runs into the timeout since the project might have dependencies to large libraries. The default timeout is 7 seconds. Increasing the value for this config option (called waitSeconds) solves it of course but it is not the right approach. 
Correct approach would be to **improve the page loading time**. One of the best technics to speed up a page loading is **minification** - the process of compressing the code. There are some good tools for minification like [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/amd.html).

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:
Requiring the same file twice with two **valid different names**, possibly two of the following:

- absolute path: '/path/to/file.js'
- relative path: './path/to/file.js'
- as a module: 'path/to/file'
- as a module on main paths config:

  paths: {
  'my/module/file' : '/path/to/file'
  }

Recently had this same issue. I did change some require paths in bulk so I knew the issue was about that.

I could clearly see on both server side logs and network debugging tab the file being served in less than a second. It was not a real timeout issue.

I tried to use [xrayrequire](https://github.com/requirejs/xrayquire) as suggested to find any circular dependency without success. I looked for requires of the conflicting file and found out I was requiring it twice with different names.

Answer (score 0):

I only get this error when running tests on Mobile Safari 6.0.0 (iOS 6.1.4). `waitSeconds: 0` has given me a successful build for now. I'll update if my build fails on this again