# Load timeout for modules with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js, amd

I'm using *requirejs* to load some libraries and dependencies.

When I just load *jQuery*, it's working perfectly:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery'
  }
});

require([
  'vendor/jquery',
  'app/init'
]);
```

**app/init.js**

```
define(
  ['jquery'],
  function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      console.log('domready');
    })
  }
)
```

But when I try to add *underscore*, in the network panel the file is correctly loaded but in the console I get a

> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: underscore

What's happening?
I also tried the *waitSeconds: 200* options inside the require.config without any success.

Below the final (broken) code as a reference:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
    underscore: 'vendor/underscore',
  }
})

require([
  'vendor/jquery',
  'vendor/underscore',
  'app/init'
])
```

**app/init.js**

```
define(
  ['jquery', 'underscore'],
  function ($, _) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      console.log('domready');
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I have the same problem , right now im catching the error and checking its type if its timeout and if it is , then reloading the browser .Hope someone helps out

Comment: @RanaDeep I hope it too, I tried to load another library instead of underscore (i.e. iScroll) but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `define` and `require` calls you sometimes refer to your modules as `"vendor/<name of module>"` and sometimes as `"<name of module>"`. This is wrong. Based on the config you show you should refer to your modules as `"<name of module>"` in all `require` and `define` calls. So always refer to jQuery and Underscore as `"jquery"` and `"underscore"`, not `"vendor/...`. When you refer to them with the full path you bypass the `shim` configuration.

Actually, you can change your `require` call to:

```
require(['app/init']);
```

You don't need to refer to jQuery and Underscore there. They will be loaded when `app/init.js` is loaded due to the `define` there requiring them.

(Also, relatively recent versions of jQuery don't need a shim because jQuery detects that it is loaded by an AMD-compatible loader and calls `define` itself. This is not the source of your problem but it is good to know.)

Comment: i had the same error. but this answer is not a solution for my case

Comment: @Anenth There are multiple causes to timeouts. The answer here addresses what was presented in the question. Not every possible case.

Comment: @Louis it works in local. Throws this error when on production with lower internet speed. :(

Comment: A possible solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279962/require-js-error-load-timeout-for-modules-backbone-jquerymobile