# a knockout "web component" is not loaded inside another component (in a SPA)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, yo

I ran into a small problem.

I have a SPA application I'm writing in knockoutjs.

I'm using **yeoman** for the scaffolding.

There's a header and a footer which remains the same.

Each page content i.e. the viewmodel and html is located inside a directory which lies inside the **components** directory.

I have a dropdown component which I want to place inside another component.
For some reason, it doesn't appear.
The name of my component is period-dropdown.

The name of the file of my component is period-dropdown.js
The name of the template (html) file of my component is period-dropdown.html
Both resides in the same directory **period-dropdown**
The **period-dropdown** resides inside the **components** directory

Here's the VM of my component:

```
define('period-dropdown', ['knockout', 'text!./period-dropdown.html'], function (ko, templateMarkup) {

function PeriodDropdown(params) {
}

return { viewModel: PeriodDropdown, template: templateMarkup };
```

});

Here is the way that component is registered:

```
 ko.components.register('period-dropdown', {require: 'components/period-dropdown/period-dropdown' });
```

I placed the html for that component inside my content page (which is also a component)

```
<period-dropdown></period-dropdown>
```

The period-dropdown component is not loaded and I get the error:

**Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: components/period-dropdown/period-dropdown**

What am I doing wrong?

thanks for the help

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279962/require-js-error-load-timeout-for-modules-backbone-jquerymobile

Comment: No I haven't. I looked at it and changed the waitSeconds. Now I don't get the error but my component is still isn't loaded.

Comment: make sure that this componet was registered before the other tha uses this.

Comment: Ok, I did it but I still don't see it.
Do you need to see more info about my files?

Comment: What I see is that the files are download i.e. the JS for the VM and the html for the template but it's not connected to the page it's in. The code doesn't reaches the Ctr of the nested component.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's working right now.
It lookes like the problem was that I set an "id" for my AMD module when there's already a registered id for that module in the startup js.
BTW, it wasn't related to the order of the components registration.
Hope it will help others who will encounter this issue.