# Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: routes,uipagestartup (Angular Application)

Tags: angular, requirejs, angular5

I have an application in `Angular5`. Any idea about why the following error comes,

```
    Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: routes,uipagestartup
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
   at makeError (require.js:7)
   at O (require.js:7)
   at require.js:7
```

I have seen multiple questions related to this like

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279962/require-js-error-load-timeout-for-modules-backbone-jquerymobile
```

I dont see any `require.config` in my application, please help me to solve/apply the solution in an `Angular` application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have issue in your dependency or **npm** please verify it by checking your 
`package.json` and `tsconfig.json`

Try to delete node_modules completely and install again by `npm install`
Verify your import in app.js

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: I didn't find any dependencies in package.json/tsconfig.json files

Comment: is it angular 5 project ? in root directory there is file package.json which contain all information of node modules ?

Comment: Yup. I have the package.json file

Comment: try to delete node_modules folder and again install modules by npm install

Comment: Tried all that.

Comment: it would be great if you share your repo ,  so i will look into it.

Comment: I can't. Its official\